# Not able to connect to google cloud platform kafka from local host

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, virtual-machine, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to connect to kafka to an instance I have created in GCP.
I have started my VM in GCP
following are the configurations in **server.properties**

```
zookeeper.connect = {external-ip of VM}:2181
 
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://{external-ip of VM}:9092
```

If I am starting my kafka by executing the command `.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties` from kafka installed directory I am getting an error.

```
[2021-06-11 16:22:44,997] INFO Session: 0x0 closed
   (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper) [2021-06-11 16:22:44,998] INFO
   EventThread shut down for session: 0x0
   (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn) [2021-06-11 16:22:45,000] INFO
   [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closed.
   (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient) [2021-06-11 16:22:45,005] ERROR
   Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown
   (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
   kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting
   for connection while in state: CONNECTING
           at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.$anonfun$waitUntilConnected$3(ZooKeeperClient.scala:271)
           at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.waitUntilConnected(ZooKeeperClient.scala:267)
           at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.<init>(ZooKeeperClient.scala:125)
           at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$.apply(KafkaZkClient.scala:1948)
           at kafka.server.KafkaServer.createZkClient$1(KafkaServer.scala:431)
           at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZkClient(KafkaServer.scala:456)
           at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:191)
           at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:109)
           at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala) [2021-06-11 16:22:45,007] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer) [2021-06-11
   16:22:45,014] INFO App info kafka.server for 0 unregistered
   (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser) [2021-06-11
   16:22:45,015] INFO shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
   [2021-06-11 16:22:45,016] ERROR Exiting Kafka. (kafka.Kafka$)
   [2021-06-11 16:22:45,018] INFO shutting down
   (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

Also if I am pinging the internal IP of VM, I am not getting any response.

Comment: You're running a windows VM for Kafka? Why? Also, the error clearly says the Zookeeper connection failed, so did you actually start Zookeeper on the address you gave to `zookeeper.connect`?

Comment: I am using Kafka image by bitnami in GCP zookeeper is preconfigured here in the VM, also if I am doing SSH to my VM then I am able to create topic successfully. So I think zookeeper is working correctly

Comment: The bitnami images are debian based, if I recall correctly, so you should not be using bat files. And if you can create a topic, then why are you trying to run `kafka-server-start` again? If you simply want to "connect to a running Kafka server", you'd use a producer/consumer, not start another server

Comment: I am connecting to Kafka trough my client which is present on my local machine and I do have a windows system, that's why I am running bat file to get Kafka up and running from my system.

Comment: Your question doesn't show a client, only a server trying to be started. Again, if you're running a Kafka server already in GCP, you shouldn't be running another one outside of GCP